# Dudas en sintaxis de código y problemas con el uso de equals

Tags: java, bluej

Agarren asiento porque esto será un poco largo. Verán estoy realizando una aplicación que permita a un usuario ingresar diversas coordenadas, y conforme hacia los retoques del menú me ocurrieron diversos problemas y esperaba que mas cabezas pudieran ayudarme, porque ya me dolió la mia de estar con esto desde la tarde. A continuación los enlistare.

**1.** Primero la cuestión del tamaño de el arraylist. Al principio del programa solo existía un menú directo, y esto provocaba algunas cuestiones que mal funcionaban el mismo, si alguien presionaba cualquier opción del menú jamás se realizaba nada, ya que todas las opciones requerían del tamaño de un arraylist y debido a que la creacion del mismo se llevaba acabo con un for que tenia condiciones para agregar el objeto, al no tener ninguno para empezar, pues en si no recorría nada, y por ente, no guardaba nada. Creí que la solución seria iniciar directamente pidiendo datos, pero esto me llevo a un 2do problema.

```
   if(confirmacion == 'n' || confirmacion == 's'){ 
            nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY); 
            for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){
                     if(nuevaCoordenada.equals(coordenadas.get(i))){
                          System.out.println("La coordenada ya existe");
                     }else{
                          System.out.println("Coordenada Agregada a la lista");
                          coordenadas.add(nuevaCoordenada); 
                     }
            }  
   }
```

**2.** al preguntar desde el principio ahora si se creaba la coordenada, pero me di cuenta que conforme se agregaban objetos, el tamaño del array crecía haciendo que el for recorriera mas espacios, y por ente cumpliera condiciones innecesarias (Al menos esta es la razón que yo le doy) y imprimiendo un exceso y innecesarios mensajes de las condicionales. Por ejemplo, la primera vez funciona correctamente, pero al ingresar otro coordenada se imprimen ambos mensajes, si se continua ingresando es como si se acumularan las impresiones, es decir, en un 2do ingreso se imprimirá el mensaje de la condición 1 y 2 2 veces, y así consecutivamente.

```
if(nuevaCoordenada.equals(coordenadas.get(i))){
     System.out.println("La coordenada ya existe");
}else{
     System.out.println("Coordenada Agregada a la lista");
     coordenadas.add(nuevaCoordenada);
```

**3** Esto me lleva a un 3er problema que me ha hecho definitivamente ya no entender nada. Verán, hace 2 dias mediante clases online nos mostraron el método equals y aun no lo domino correctamente, de hecho prácticamente no tengo ni idea de como se estructura el método, pero aun así, intente usarlos en base a un ejemplo (sin declarar el método porque aun no lo comprendo muy bien). Y aquí esta la parte que me confunde mas.

```
for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){
                    if(nuevaCoordenada.equals(coordenadas.get(i))){
                        System.out.println("La Coordenada fue encontrada: ");
                        System.out.println(coordenadas.get(i).imprimirCoordenadas(i));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("La Coordenada no fue encontrada");
                    }
                }
```

Como pueden ver, esta parte es prácticamente igual que la primera, pero cuando accedo a ella funciona correctamente, es decir, nunca se cumple el equals, a pesar de que lo obligo a intentar cumplirse (ingresando los mismos datos), cosa que tiene sentido ya que no tengo ni el método equals que se supone se debe de escribir en la clase de los objetos.

De aca surgen las dudas.

1. ¿Podrían ayudarme a pensar en una estructura que me evite ese problema de que se acumulen los prints en el primer for así como quizá una solución a evitar tener que iniciar el programa preguntando una coordenada?
2. ¿Por que el if si cumple inclusive algo que no debería, y 2 condiciones a la vez?
3. ¿Me podrían decir como se elaboraría el método equals usando mis variables? (PuntoX y PuntoY) De lo único que tengo conocimiento es que al parecer se declaran el la propia clase de CoordenadaCartesiana, pero hasta ahí

**POR SI QUIEREN PROBARLO USTEDES MISMOS**

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    CoordenadaCartesiana nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(); // inicializamos el objeto CoordenadaCartesiana
    ArrayList<CoordenadaCartesiana> coordenadas = new ArrayList<CoordenadaCartesiana>(); //  iniciamos y declaramos el array list que guardara objetos de tipo coordenada
    
    double puntoX; // variable que almacenara punto X
    double puntoY; // variable que almacenara punto Y
    char confirmacion; // confirmacion de ingreso de nueva coordenada
    int menu; // variable que manejara las funciones del menu 
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
    puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado 
    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y           
    puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado 
    nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY); // los datos seran guardados creando un nuevo objeto coordenada
    coordenadas.add(nuevaCoordenada); // dicho objeto es añadido a la lista de coordenadas
    do{
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingresa el numero correspondiente a la opcion"); 
            System.out.println("1. Agregar Coordenada | 2. Buscar Coordenada | 3. Mostrar Lista | 4. Salir ");
            menu = entrada.nextInt();
            if(menu == 1){
                do{
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
                    puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado 
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y
                    puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado 
                    System.out.println("¿Quiere ingresar otra coordenada? (s/n)"); // preguntar por siguiente coordenada 
                    confirmacion = entrada.next().charAt(0); // guardar respuesta
                    if(confirmacion == 'n' || confirmacion == 's'){ // independientemente de la respuesta, se pasaran los datos
                        nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY); // los datos seran guardados creando un nuevo objeto coordenada
                        for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){
                            if(nuevaCoordenada.equals(coordenadas.get(i))){
                                System.out.println("La coordenada ya existe");
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("Coordenada Agregada a la lista");
                                coordenadas.add(nuevaCoordenada); // dicho objeto es añadido a la lista de coordenadas
                            }
                        }  
                    }
                }while(confirmacion != 'n'); // si presiona no, el bucle se detendra, creando el objeto con la ultima informacion ingresada
            }else if(menu == 2){
                System.out.println("¿Que coordenada desea buscar?");
                System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
                puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado 
                System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y
                puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado 
                nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY);
                for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){
                    if(nuevaCoordenada.equals(coordenadas.get(i))){
                        System.out.println("La Coordenada fue encontrada: ");
                        System.out.println(coordenadas.get(i).imprimirCoordenadas(i));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("La Coordenada no fue encontrada");
                    }
                }
            }else if(menu == 3){
                for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){ // recorremos la lista
                    System.out.println(coordenadas.get(i).imprimirCoordenadas(i)); // imprimimos el string con la estructura correspondiente ya hecha en el metodo                                                      // pedimos el parametro posicion para poder imprimir el numero al que pertenece en la lista
                }
            }
        }while(menu <= 0 || menu > 4);
    }while(menu != 4);
    System.out.println("CERRADO");
}
```

**clase de coordenada**

```
public class CoordenadaCartesiana
{

private double puntoX; 
private double puntoY; 

public CoordenadaCartesiana()
{
    this.puntoX = 0.0; 
    this.puntoY = 0.0; 
}

public CoordenadaCartesiana(double puntoX, double puntoY){
    this.puntoX = puntoX; 
    this.puntoY = puntoY; 
}

public double getPuntoX(){
    return puntoX;
}

public double getPuntoY(){
    return puntoY;
}

public void setPuntoX(double nuevoPuntoX){
    this.puntoX = nuevoPuntoX;
}

public void setPuntoY(double nuevoPuntoY){
    this.puntoY = nuevoPuntoY;
}

public String imprimirCoordenadas(int posicion){
    String cadena; // string que guardara la estructura de la coordenada
    cadena = posicion + ": (" + puntoX + ", " + puntoY + ")"; // se le asigna la estructura = (puntoX, puntoY)
    return cadena; // se retorna la cadena
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asi queda sin moverle mucho a tu codigo

```html
package pruebaAyuda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ayuda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        // inicializamos el objeto CoordenadaCartesiana
        // iniciamos y declaramos
        // el array list que guardara objetos de tipo coordenada
        ArrayList<CoordenadaCartesiana> coordenadas = new ArrayList<CoordenadaCartesiana>(); 

        double puntoX; // variable que almacenara punto X
        double puntoY; // variable que almacenara punto Y
        char confirmacion; // confirmacion de ingreso de nueva coordenada
        int menu; // variable que manejara las funciones del menu

        //por defecto no hay ningun valor repetido dentro del ArrayList ya
        //que es la primera vez que se ejecuta el programa
        boolean isRepetido = false;

        do {
            do {
                System.out.println("========== MENU ==========");
                System.out.println("Ingresa el numero correspondiente a la opcion");
                System.out.println("1. Agregar Coordenada | 2. Buscar Coordenada | 3. Mostrar Lista | 4. Salir ");
                menu = entrada.nextInt();
                if (menu == 1) {
                    System.out.println("======== Ingresar una nueva Coordenada ==========");
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
                        puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y
                        puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado

                        //recorremos el ArrayList buscando X y Y del usuario introducido
                        //par saber si se repite una coordenada
                        //Nota este  for( CoordenadaCartesiana punto : coordenadas )
                        //es lo mismo que for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++)
                        for (CoordenadaCartesiana punto : coordenadas) {
                            if (punto.getPuntoX() == puntoX && punto.getPuntoY() == puntoY) {
                                isRepetido = true;
                                System.out.println("La coordenada ya existe");
                            }
                        }
                        //Si IsRepetido no es verdadero o sea que es falso quiere decir que no hay repetido

                        if (!isRepetido) {
                            System.out.println("Coordenada Agregada a la lista");
                            coordenadas.add(new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY)); // dicho objeto es añadido a la
                                                                                        // lista de coordenadas
                        }

                        // Regresamos a false porque si en la siguiente vuelta no es repetido y no lo
                        // regresamo a false quedara con verdadero y si no es repetido pero la variable esta
                        //en verdadero no agregara esa nueva coordenada
                        isRepetido = false;

                        // preguntar por siguiente coordenada
                        System.out.println("¿Quiere ingresar otra coordenada? (s/n)"); 
                        confirmacion = entrada.next().charAt(0); // guardar respuesta
                        System.out.println();
                        // si presiona no, el bucle se detendra, creando el objeto con la ultima informacion ingresada
                    } while (confirmacion != 'n'); 
                }else if (menu == 2) {
                    System.out.println("======== Buscar una Coordenada ==========");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("¿Que coordenada desea buscar?");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
                    puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y
                    puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado

                    CoordenadaCartesiana nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY);

                    if (coordenadas.size() == 0) {
                        System.out.println("No es posible realizar la busqueda, debido aque no hay ninguna coordena guardada aun");
                    } else {
                        int posicion = 1;
                        boolean encontrada = false;

                        for (CoordenadaCartesiana punto : coordenadas) {
                            if (nuevaCoordenada.getPuntoX() == punto.getPuntoX() && nuevaCoordenada.getPuntoY() == punto.getPuntoY()) {
                                encontrada = true;
                                
                                break;
                            }

                            ++posicion;
                        }

                        if (encontrada) {
                            System.out.println("La Coordenada fue encontrada: ");
                            //del ArrayList agarra el objeto que esta en la posicon e imprime en que posicion se encontro
                            //posicion le quitamos 1 para poder encontrar en el ArrayList el objeto en su posicion
                            //correcta ya que si no le restamos 1 cuando el ArrayList tenga solo un elemento
                            //esta estra en la posicon 0 pero como posicion estara en 1 .MArcara error ya que 
                            //en la posicion 1 no hay nada solamente en la posicion 0
                            System.out.println(coordenadas.get(posicion - 1).imprimirCoordenadas(posicion));
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("La Coordenada no fue encontrada");
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                } else if (menu == 3) {
                    // recorremos la lista
                    for (int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++) { 
                        System.out.println(coordenadas.get(i).imprimirCoordenadas(i)); 
                        // imprimimos el string con la estructura correspondiente ya
                        // hecha en el metodo pedimos el parametro posicion para
                        // poder imprimir el numero al que pertenece en la lista
                    }
                }
            }while (menu <= 0 || menu > 4);
        }while (menu != 4);
        System.out.println("CERRADO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por extenderte, la verdad las notas me ayudaron mucho a comprender, pero me siguió quedando una duda con el for que usaste, comprendo que sirve para recorrer la lista, ¿pero exactamente en que momento ese objeto se crea y toma valores para realizar comparaciones?. Pregunto por lo de punto.getPuntoX()  y eso, ¿los toma de forma implícita o algo por el estilo? me surge la duda porque según tengo entendido debería de tomar los valores como tipo nuevaCoordenada(puntoX, puntoY). Agradecería si me pudieras aclarar eso pls, o pasar un enlace, lo que te sea mas fácil y oportuno.

Comment: System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado
System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y
puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado
 
ahora la ingresa y se guardan. ejemplo X = 5 y Y = 6

Despues biene el FOR que recorre el ArrayList<CoordenadaCartesiana>
en busuqeda de una coordenada. pero recuerda que es la primera vez que entras aqui por lo tanto aun  ArrayList<CoordenadaCartesiana> toda via esta vacia, solamente tenemos guardado en variables XyY

Comment: ahora viene la parte de correr el ArrayList y ver si la coordenada agregada por ti no esta ya salvada y se hace en esta parte.

for (CoordenadaCartesiana punto : coordenadas) {
if (punto.getPuntoX() == puntoX && punto.getPuntoY() == puntoY) {
 isRepetido = true;
 System.out.println("La coordenada ya existe");
  }
 }

Comment: ahora recordando que este for (CoordenadaCartesiana punto : coordenadas)

es lo mismo que for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++)

entonces estamos preguntado coordenada tiene algo? es mayor que 0.

sabemos que es 0 porque es la primera vez que entramos a esta opcion CASE 1 por lo tanto no entra al FOR ya que no podemos guardar la coordenada del usuario XyY toda via en el objeto CoordenadaCartesiana porque primero necesitamos saber que no este ya guardado.

Comment: como no entro al FOR porque no hay nada aun salvado y nuestra variable que hicimos para saber si hay algo repetido es falso isRepetido = falso; pues queda en falso y entra al if ( ! isRepetido) y ahora si se crea el objeto

CoordenadaCartesiana con las coordenadas dada por el usuario CoordenadaCartesiana (X,Y)

Comment: Despues si tu quieres hacer otra nueva coordenada .ahora si entrara al 
for (CoordenadaCartesiana punto : coordenadas) ya que nuestro ArrayLista ya es mayor a 0

y aremos es entrar al ArrayList y como nuestro ArrayList es de tipo CoordenadaCartesiana necitamos una variable de tipo CoordenadaCartesiana  ya que este es el tipo de objeto que vamos a obtener del ArrayList.

Comment: Si nuestro ArrayList fuera de tipo String ArrayList<String>(); para recorrerlo necesitariamos una varible de tipo String algo a si

for(String cadena : cadenas)

Si fuera de tipo object ArrayLsit<Object>

for(Object objeto : objetos)

y etc para cada tipo de  OBjeto, bueno espero haberme hecho entender

Comment: Oh ya veo, ya comprendí lo que dices, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1):

Para no tener que pedir un valor al iniciar y creo que esto resuelve el resto de problemas:

```
// primero revisar si la coordenada existe
boolean existe = coordenadas
.stream()
.anyMatch(c -> c.getPuntoX() == finalPuntoX && c.getPuntoY() == finalPuntoY);

// si existe mostrar el mensaje
if(existe){
    System.out.println("La coordenada ya existe");
}else{
    System.out.println("Coordenada Agregada a la lista");
    coordenadas.add(nuevaCoordenada); 
}
```

El código:

```
boolean existe = coordenadas
 .stream()
 .anyMatch(c -> c.getPuntoX() == finalPuntoX && c.getPuntoY() == finalPuntoY);
```

Puede reemplazarse por:

```
boolean existe = false;

for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){
    if(coordenadas.get(i).getPuntoX() == puntoX 
             && coordenadas.get(i).getPuntoY() == puntoY)
    {
        existe = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Código completo

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        CoordenadaCartesiana nuevaCoordenada;
        ArrayList<CoordenadaCartesiana> coordenadas = new ArrayList<>(); //  iniciamos y declaramos el array list que guardara objetos de tipo coordenada

        double puntoX; // variable que almacenara punto X
        double puntoY; // variable que almacenara punto Y
        char confirmacion; // confirmacion de ingreso de nueva coordenada
        int menu; // variable que manejara las funciones del menu


        do{
            do{
                System.out.println("Ingresa el numero correspondiente a la opcion");
                System.out.println("1. Agregar Coordenada | 2. Buscar Coordenada | 3. Mostrar Lista | 4. Salir ");
                menu = entrada.nextInt();
                if(menu == 1){
                    do{
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
                        puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y
                        puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado


                        nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY); // los datos seran guardados creando un nuevo objeto coordenada

                        double finalPuntoX = puntoX;
                        double finalPuntoY = puntoY;
                        boolean existe = coordenadas.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.getPuntoX() == finalPuntoX && c.getPuntoY() == finalPuntoY);

                        if(existe){
                            System.out.println("La coordenada ya existe");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Coordenada Agregada a la lista");
                            coordenadas.add(nuevaCoordenada); // dicho objeto es añadido a la lista de coordenadas
                        }



                        System.out.println("¿Quiere ingresar otra coordenada? (s/n)"); // preguntar por siguiente coordenada
                        confirmacion = entrada.next().charAt(0); // guardar respuesta

                    }while(confirmacion != 'n'); // si presiona no, el bucle se detendra, creando el objeto con la ultima informacion ingresada
                }else if(menu == 2){
                    System.out.println("¿Que coordenada desea buscar?");
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto X"); // pedir punto X
                    puntoX = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el punto Y"); // pedir punto Y
                    puntoY = entrada.nextDouble(); // guardar dato ingresado
                    nuevaCoordenada = new CoordenadaCartesiana(puntoX, puntoY);
                    for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){
                        if(nuevaCoordenada.equals(coordenadas.get(i))){
                            System.out.println("La Coordenada fue encontrada: ");
                            System.out.println(coordenadas.get(i).imprimirCoordenadas(i));
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("La Coordenada no fue encontrada");
                        }
                    }
                }else if(menu == 3){
                    for(int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++){ // recorremos la lista
                        System.out.println(coordenadas.get(i).imprimirCoordenadas(i)); // imprimimos el string con la estructura correspondiente ya hecha en el metodo                                                      // pedimos el parametro posicion para poder imprimir el numero al que pertenece en la lista
                    }
                }
            }while(menu <= 0 || menu > 4);
        }while(menu != 4);
        System.out.println("CERRADO");
    }
```